# Could a steam juicer be used to desalinate water?

Tags: water-purification, drinking-water

Could someone use a steam juicer to desalinate water? The juicer is used on a stovetop and the steam rises to the fruit in the top basket and the juice collects in the middle pot.

I think it might work but does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: As described, it sounds rather inefficient. A still normally uses a water jacket to cool the steam and maximise condensation. The water heated by this is then used to supply the still. You may be able to improvise something along the same lines, otherwise you'll use a lot of fuel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can as what you would do is use heat to turn the salt water to steam and then collect the steam and turn it back into liquid water.

It works on the same principle as a regular distiller, and if you really wanted to you could get a purpose-built water distiller but a steam juicer will work as well.

> Yesterday a friend and I got to looking at a steam juicer a**nd realized that they can be used as an improvised small still**.  The size we have would distill somewhere around a ½ gallon at a time.  Larger ones would do more.  This could be used to distill water for batteries, to **desalinize sea water**  or to make small batches of alcohol for medical use

[Source](https://preparednessadvice.com/water_purification/improvising-a-still-from-a-steam-juicer/)

Comment: I agree, but would add that relying only on distilled water for hydration for a longer period is [bad for your health](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/317698.php). I wouldn't drink distilled water at all when exercising, because the electrolytes lost through perspiration need to be replaced to avoid [hyponatremia](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/hyponatremia/symptoms-causes/syc-20373711).